# Shortcode with conditional tag to show different style

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a short code that displays some content in two different pages.

Both sites have different styles to show the same content of the short code.

However, conditional tags are not working properly.

Here the code:

```
function comunicacionpdf_sc($atts, $content = null) {
        extract(shortcode_atts(array("url" => 'http://www.example.com/file.pdf'), $atts));
        if (is_page('comunicaciones')) {
            return 'test';
            //$output .= '<h6><a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank">Descargar PDF</a></h6>';
        } else {
            //$output .= '<div class="cd_comunicacionespdf"><a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank">Descargar Aqu&iacute;</a></div>';
            return 'no-test';
        }
    }
    add_shortcode('comunicacionpdf', 'comunicacionpdf_sc');
```

Please ignore the commented output, that will actually look in the frontend.

From already, thank you very much for your help

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Where does the shortcode get executed at? is there multiple queries? have you tried doing `wp_reset_query()` before executing the shortcode?

Comment: Amal Murali: This code only show second conditional, i need that display the content in two pages: Comunicaciones and single page. In single page the shortcode have one css style, and in "Comunicaciones" page, other css style, but the content is same.